# Magento 2 Recargar control custom al cambiar shipping method

Tags: magento2

Tengo un metodo de pago custom que tiene adicional un combo de cuotas, al seleccionar el shipping method si el total del carrito cambia debo recargar el combo de cuotas con el nuevo valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ConfigProvider
Donde está definido el método para cargar las cuotas de acuerdo al monto del carrito

```
<?php
   namespace NisseiStore\Fraccionate\Model;

   use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class CustomConfigProvider
 * 
 * @package NisseiStore\Fraccionate\Model
*/
class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \NisseiStore\Fraccionate\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_helper;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase CustomConfigProvider
     * 
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \NisseiStore\Fraccionate\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \NisseiStore\Fraccionate\Helper\Data $helper
    ){
        $this->_logger          = $logger;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_helper          = $helper;        
    }


    public function getCuotas(){
        try{
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
            $quote = $cart->getQuote();
            // Array para retornar cuotero            
            $result   = array();
            $contador = 0;
            $monto    = $quote->getGrandTotal();
            
            // Obtiene el cuotero de acuerdo al monto del carrito
            $cuotero = $this->_helper->getCuotero($monto);

            if ($cuotero != null){
                // Recorre el cuotero y carga el array
                foreach($cuotero as $fila){
                    $result[$contador] = $fila->periodos . ' X ' . number_format($fila->cuota_mensual, 0, ',', '.');

                    $contador ++;
                }
            }

            return $result;

        } catch(Exception $e){
            $this->_logger->info('FRACCIONATE ERROR', ['Método' => 'getCuota | CustomConfigProvider', 'Error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
  
    public function getConfig(){  
        $config = [
          'payment' => [
            'fraccionate' => [
                    'monto' => 0,
                    'cuotas' => $this->getCuotas(),
              ],
          ],
        ];
      
        return $config;
    }
}
```

Render fraccionate.js
KO para llamar al config provider y enlazar con el combo de cuotas y mostrar las opciones de acuerdo al monto

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'jquery',
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information'
    ],
    function (Component, placeOrderAction, $, url, getPaymentInformation) {
        'use strict';
        
        return Component.extend({          
            defaults: {
                redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,
                template: 'NisseiStore_Fraccionate/payment/fraccionate'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                this.setfee = function () {
                    this.setFee();
                };

                this._super();
            },            
            getCode: function() {
                return 'fraccionate';
            },
            isActive: function() {
                console.log("Is active");
                return true;
            },
            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            },
            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                var cuota;
                cuota = $('#fraccionate_selected_fee').text();

                var redirectUrl = url.build('fraccionate/redirect/?cuota=' + cuota);
                $.mage.redirect(redirectUrl); 
            },
            getCuotas: function() {
                return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.fraccionate.cuotas;
            },    
            getCuotaList: function() {                
                return _.map(this.getCuotas(), function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        'value': key,
                        'type': value 
                    }
                });
            },                     
            setFee: function(){
                var cuota;
                console.log("Cambio cuota...");

                cuota = $('#fraccionate_payment_profile_id option:selected').text();
                $('#fraccionate_selected_fee').text(cuota);
                console.log("Cuota TEXT: " + $('#fraccionate_selected_fee').text());
            },
            validate: function () {
                var cuotaValidationResult = false;
                var cuota = $('#fraccionate_selected_fee').text();
                if(cuota.trim() != ''){ //should use Regular expression in real store.
                    cuotaValidationResult = true;
                }

                // Retorna el resultado
                return cuotaValidationResult;
            } 
        });        
    }
);
```

HTML para el checkout donde se realiza el enlace del control para la carga de las cuotas. Aquí funciona solo para la primera carga, si varía el valor del carrito ya no recarga el control con los valores actuales

fraccionate.html

```
<div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <form id="co-transparent-form-fraccionate-assisted" class="form fraccionate_form" data-bind="" method="post" action="#" novalidate="novalidate"></form>
            <input id="fraccionate_selected_fee" type="hidden">
            <select name="payment[subscription_id]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                                options: getCuotaList(),
                                optionsValue: 'value',
                                optionsText: 'type',
                                optionsCaption: $t('Seleccione una opción de cuota...'),
                                event: {change: setfee }
                                ">
            </select>
        </form>
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>        
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar" id="fraccionate-actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Continue'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Dónde esta tu código? poco se te puede ayudar con lo que nos presentas.

Comment: Gracias Enrique por las sugerencias. He agregado más información, espero pueda ser útil.